# Displaying a different UITable by selecting a cell from a previous UITable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to ios and `Objective-C` programming, and am having a few problems. I want to create an app with four tiers (hierarchy).

The first three tiers must have TableViews and the last one must have Labels and Textfields.

Through `Storyboard` I am able to create and populate the three tier tables as well as the fourth tier with the labels and the textfields (I have embedded each of the tables, etc in its own navigation controller.

Each table can have a number of cells. Each cell must point to a different table in the following tier (if I select the first cell in the top tier it must display the first table in the second tier ... etc and if I select the second cell in the top tier table it must display the second table in the second tier .. etc.

At the moment if I select any of the cells in a table I don't get the different tables in the next tier but the same table in the next tier.

Secondly : the values of the selected cells in each tier (table) must be available for use in the final tier of the hierarchy where I want to manipulate the selected data

Thanks very much

Comment: Herewith an extraction from my program :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of your table view

write

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
 YourDestinationViewController *myVC = (YourDestinationViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourDestinationViewController"]
[self presentModalViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks very much. The solution to the first part of my questions works perfectly .  The second part of the question I solved myself by using :  NSString *copyCell = cell.textLabel.text; UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];  [pb setString:copyCell] in the first TableView and then retrieving the data from the Pasteboard in the following TableView